# can I combine meta or do I have to use only one?

Tags: php, javascript, html, meta

I used to use this meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

Now I want to change meta so that compatibility view in IE9 is disabled:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Now I don't understand much bout the first meta but my question is that can I only use one of the meta out of the two or can I combine them to include both of them? Which way would you recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am right in saying, you're question is actually "Whats the best way to do it, in terms of minimizing page size and improving site quality?"

As far as I know each META tag like that must be declared separately, because you are declaring 1 value for each.

Comment: So write it as `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

Comment: Yes, keep them and any others all separate

Answer (score 2):

You can have as many `<meta>` tags as you want.

Comment: I think his question is more, which way is better to do it for site performance, as opposed to "Can I have more than one META tag" :)

Comment: Yh my fault, I meant which way is best way